# What's the attitude towards "Give me answer, I don't RTFD" questions?

Tags: discussion

[Using systemd can I run a specific application whenever my server/worker exits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468898/using-systemd-can-i-run-a-specific-application-whenever-my-server-worker-exits) (I told him to read about some documentation)

[Can grub load a kernel from HTTP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228452/can-grub-load-a-kernel-from-http) (in the comments, he refuses to read any kind of manual)

[How to ExecStartPre another systemd unit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469313/how-to-execstartpre-another-systemd-unit) (clearly didn't listen to me because nobody write a service file like that after a little document reading)

Anyone can explain to me about that?  Is that attitude welcomed in this stackexchange community as long as it's a properly described and not duplicate question? Does this community even care about such situation?

To be honest, I think such questions and comments and even account should be banned for any tech-related Q&A community.

Comment: No. Sadly the view here is that people unwilling to read documentation will somehow experience a Damascene conversion here, especially if they are pandered to.

Comment: None of these questions seem to match the characterisation you've given them to me, to be honest. I don't see anywhere that "in the comments, he refuses to read any kind of manual", for example.

Comment: @Micheal The second question you didn't see it in the comments of he saying "manuals won't provide any useful information"? Are you kidding me or you just refuse to admit that this is exactly the kind of people I'm talking about? Even if you are right, did you read the first and third example I give?

Comment: Since the comment simply doesn't say that, no, I didn't see him saying it, and neither did you. ([The comment in question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228452/can-grub-load-a-kernel-from-http#comment389789_228452): "The manual? Who would have thought such a thing could contain useful information?"). I can certainly think of some cases that might match what you're describing, but these are very inapposite examples. If you have others matching the pattern you're concerned about perhaps you could [edit] those in to illustrate what you're talking about to people more clearly.

Comment: For the other two, they might be duplicates (I'm not certain enough on systemd configuration to say for sure), and duplicates from the same user are definitely a bad sign. I don't see anything especially unreasonable about any of the questions in isolation though. They're certainly far from the worst we get and at least #2 is a genuinely interesting question.

Comment: @Micheal #1 #3 are not the same, They really aren't according to the LITERAL DESCRIPTION. Although I am very sure they're both X-Y and very similar. For your knowledge, Nobody use a service name for PreExec Start, it should be a command. A person who RTFD a little bit would know that, I didn't randomly guess he didn't read doc, I KNOW he didn't.

Comment: Yes, it is a good question, that's what I said as "a properly described and not duplicate question" . Just the comment refusing to read docs, THIS IS SICK. IT encourages people to ask question, waiting for answers, no effort needed.

Comment: I think you're misreading the comment and that that reaction is pretty extreme even then. You clearly don't like this person in particular, so my advice would be to just give their questions a miss entirely. There are many people here who skip over certain authors' questions for various reasons and it's a lot healthier for them than the alternative. As I said, though, if you have **other** examples, *ideally not all from the same user*, that might be helpful for addressing the issue you're seeing as a general topic here, and I encourage you to edit them in & say a bit more on what you've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Many questions on this site can be answered by referring to the relevant documentation. Even questions directly addressed by the documentation can be useful for the next person who is facing the same situation.

Depending on the exact question there might be also other ways to answer the question than only the answer provided by the documentation. When writing an answer to such question you can cite the documentation or provide a link for further information.

Some low quality questions can be improved by simply removing non-relevant details/information (and possibly some rephrasing to better focus on the exact issue). Having one good question is useful as new questions on same topic can then be marked as duplicates.